# Java : Is it possible to deserialize objects without reflection

Tags: java, reflection, deserialization

My understanding is that deserializing any object uses reflection underneath, always, no matter what be the case.

Heard somebody advocating the contrary.

Please help out in validating this understands ng. Is there any such technique in Java (or any other language) which does not depends upon reflection.

Edit : No opinions are being asked here on the preference of any approach. This is simply to be aware about any possible approach exists or not ??

Comment: Deserialization means you have to create instances of specific classes, but you don't know which ones. You need reflection for that.

Comment: The only alternative would imply limiting your deserializing code to a finite set of supported types and have explicit handlers (factories) for each.

Comment: Can't see anything calling for opinions here...

Comment: How in the world.is this opinion based. This is a simple question about the possible approaches to deserialize objects. Nothing is being asked in terms of pros/cons. Request the other moderators to help re-opening this

Comment: @Holger : Doesn't the alternate approach too requires reflection. Can you please share an example ? Would help

Comment: The factories are objects of classes implementing a common interface, like `Function<PersistentData,Object>` and the deserializing code has a map like `Map<PersistentIdentifier,Function<PersistentData,Object>>` to look up the factory and delegate. Technically, any kind of parser not consisting of monolithic code is in fact a similar kind of deserializer.

Answer (score 4):

Basically there are two ways to deserialize objects (from JSON, from the database or even from Javas own Serialization).

The one nearly everyone is using relies on reflection to learn about the structure of the Object to create and to populate the structure.

The other way creates factories for the objects it needs to desirialize during build phase. For this it creates a lot of classes and has to know at build time which objects it will need to deserialize. The only framework I know of that follows this path is [micronaut](https://micronaut.io/).

Even if you provide reflectionless methods to populate your objects (this can be done), we still need reflection to find and call these methods.